# Check if url passed is part of the application page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, relative-url

I need help in this. For example I have 3 pages (Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx, Page3.aspx) and I also have a modal popup where the user enters a url. Now, I want to test if the url that was entered is part of the application that I have.

What I've done so far is to use the `Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)` method but it doesn't seem to fit the requirement because it does not work when the user passes `google.com`, it treats it like a relative url and not an absolute url.

Below are some urls which I test on and its respective result:

- www.google.com [Absolute]
- yahoo.com [Absolute]
- Page1.aspx?Name=Lucio [Relative]
- http://MyApplication/docs/Page3.aspx [Relative]

Answer (score 0):

*I want to test if the url that was entered is part of the application that I have.*

For this you can use the `location` of the `window` object available:

```js
function TryCreate(url) {
  if (url == window.location.host) {
    return "relative";
  } else if (url.split('?')[0] == window.location.host && url.slice(url.indexOf('?')) == window.location.search) {
    return "relative";
  } else {
    return "absolute";
  }
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('pre').textContent = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value + ":" + TryCreate(document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type='text'>
<button>check url</button>
<pre></pre>


<sub>due to some restriction you should add this url "stacksnippets.net"</sub>
```

Comment: could you try it with Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx, Page3.aspx? because it doesn't seem to work despite my changes on this.

Comment: _due to some restriction you should add this url "stacksnippets.net"_ you can see this in the answer. And BTW what issue do you face in it.

Comment: _stacksnippets.net_ is the `window.location` in the snippet if you run it.

Comment: Actually, the `stacksnippets.net` is just one page. How about the rest of the pages (Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx, Page3.aspx)?